# What is the official name for the scroll-pop up technology?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, scroll

The page pops up/ shows something after you have scrolled to a certain depth.
What is the technology called?

Example:

[Asp-Tutorial](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/)
Scrolling down a little bit will show a 'share' and 'download' border.

[Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Coin-Purse-from-a-Tube-Container)
Scrolling down almost to the end shows Google Plus follow button.

Comment: Wikihow calls it a "sliderbox", the ASP tutorial calls it a "fixed-bar". Doesn't sound like there is an official name.

Comment: Maybe a "slide out box" or a "flyout card".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology rather than a technical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click on practically anything on a website, it will give you an option to "inspect element." Using that you can see at least some of how the programmer of a website did something (assuming you know how to read code).

Now, I'd assume there are multiple programming languages that can be used to do that, but both of those are done with javascript, it appears. That is what I found looking at the code, using the aforementioned technique. You may want to learn to code html and javascript before attempting to read it, but `<script>` with no attributes(so not `<script type="perl">`) signifies javascript. The deprecated(old) version of this was: `<script type="text/javascript">`. Since the js tag references a different file on asp.net(as signified by the `src=` attribute), you can't view how they did it in javascript. Wikihow's is programmed quite confusingly, but you might be able to figure out how it works, it all appears to be there.

Sorry if I've covered overly basic information, I don't know what level you are on with programming.

Comment: The OP is asking what it's called, not how to make one.